# pyramid view for 503 subclass

Tags: python, pyramid

I'd like to serve some templated html along with a 503 status code when I hit a particular case in my app. Subclassing the pyramid 503 exception represents this handily:

```
from pyramid.httpexceptions import HTTPServiceUnavailable
class PleaseWait(HTTPServiceUnavailable):
    pass

def business_logic():
    if not_ready():
        raise PleaseWait()
```

What I can't figure out is a clean way to hook up a template to `PleaseWait`. This nearly works, but gives code 200:

```
config.add_view(
    renderer='templates/please_wait.jinja2',
    context='my_app.PleaseWait',
)
```

This completely works, but seems messy:

```
@view_config(context=PleaseWait, renderer='templates/please_wait.jinja2')
def please_wait(exc, request):
    request.response.status = 503
    return {}
```

---

This also works, but seems maybe bizarre: `request.response = exc`.

Comment: Instead of `raise`  can you do `return` where you construct the full HTTP response, including a rendered template in the response body?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa I would receive an error like "no such renderer factory: jinja2", although I'm sure I correctly import the jinja2 factory in my config. I'm able to render other views' jinja2 templates just fine.

Comment: If there is an error can you post a full traceback for the error? Also related configuration Python code.

Comment: That last one where you set the response.status code yourself is the way that Pyramid developers use.

`exc` in your `please_wait()` view is a full Response and thus can be set as `request.response` or you could even `return exc` to get the same effect.